# Why are real estate records public?

Tags: united-states, privacy, property

The government is very restricted on what information it may disclose about you and under what circumstances.  For example, I can't look up your car's license plate number to find out who you are.  I can't ask the police for your criminal record.  I can't look at your taxes or your income.  I can't ask for your name or even confirm if you *have* any of those things I mentioned.  In most states, the DMV, the police, the revenue department, and other agencies are all forbidden from disclosing any information about you without your permission, or without an official reason.

But the county auditor's office? They'll tell me pretty much everything they know about you.  I can go to most any U.S. county's web site, pick an address, and find out the name of the owner (which is often the person who lives there), their phone number, the value of their property, when it was purchased and for how much, the taxes paid on it, who the lienholder is, what permits they've drawn on it, etc, etc.  That's a lot of information that would be considered private by any other metric. And yet it's freely available to anyone who wants it.

Why is the government so tight-lipped about seemingly innocuous things about you (like whether or not you have a driver's license), but so open about this potentially sensitive property information?

Comment: Can you actually find out the owner's name of a given property for free? Say in New Zealand this is only possible for $5.

Comment: @Greendrake; I did this recently on my own house. It even listed the name of the previous owner and had pictures of what it looked like back then.

Comment: @Greendrake I once forgot which house on a particular street that a friend lived on, and was able to look it up online (using info that was likely sourced from where the OP is talking about). It told me the address, who owns the house, and even the phone number. Then sites like Zillow will tell you about past sales of the house, plus  stuff like taxes and such. Now, those aren’t *directly* from the government, but it’s all info that pretty much had to be sourced from them.